# Is $\Omega$ infinite or finite?

Tags: probability

I’m reading [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/bjps/article/69/2/509/2669779) by Benci et al on infinitesimal probabilities.

They formulated a principle they called the conditional probability principle (CPP):

> Let $\{\lambda_n\}$ be a family of events such that $\lambda_n \subseteq \lambda_{n+1}$ and $\Omega = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \lambda_n$; then eventually, $$P_k(\lambda_n)>0$$ and for any event $A \subseteq \Omega$, we have that $$P_k(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P_k(A|\lambda_n)$$

What puzzles me is that the family of events $\{\lambda_n\}$ is a family of *finite* subsets. This is their stipulation. They said that adopting CPP is equivalent to adopting $\sigma$-additivity. My question is since ${\lambda_n}$ is a family of *finite* subsets, is $\Omega$ finite too? I’m thinking that since all $\lambda_n$ is finite, and $\lambda_n \subseteq \lambda_{n+1}$, the union would be finite too?

Comment: It can  be countably infinite, for example if $\Omega=\mathbb N$ and $\lambda_n=\{1,\dots,n\}$. I believe that it cannot be uncountable.

Answer (score 3):

Take $\lambda_n=\{1, \dots n\}$ which is finite. Then $\Omega=\bigcup \lambda_n=\mathbb N$ is infinite.

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, $\Omega$ will be countably infinite.

Indeed, for $\Omega$ to be finite, it requires that there exists some $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $\lambda_{n+1}=\lambda_n$. Otherwise, we will have infinitely many steps that add at least one element each, and therefore we will end up with infinitely many elements.

$\Omega$ cannot be uncountably infinite, however, because it is the union of countably many finite sets.